# how to exclude strings with symbols using Java Regex

Tags: java, regex, symbols

I'm looking for a way, using Java regex/regexp, to test if a string has anything but letters, numbers, or _'s in it (no symbols).

I tried this, but it accepted all strings. This is not the exact code, but it will work.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\w]");  //also tried ("\w")
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(x);
if(!matcher.find()){
System.out.println("Valid String");
}else{
System.out.println("Invalid String");
}
```

Comment: Start at the javadoc, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis has a point. Without you posting regexes you've tried and why they're not suitable, this is just a "give me code" question, and those don't tend to go over well here. The javadoc on the `Pattern` class should help you get started; once you've tried some things, you'll have better source material for a question and be better able to understand the answers.

Comment: Please post the exact code (including the string against which you are testing) by editing your question - you will get more useful answers.

Comment: I am not entirely sure why my question has been put on-hold (I understand how the on-hold system works), If anyone, especially those who put my question on-hold, could give some incite, that would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the following regex:

```
^\w*$
```

to match "only word characters" in the entire string. Depending on how you enter the string, you may need to escape the backslash, leaving you with

```
^\\w*$
```

As the correct expression. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Ok, this worked, but I dont have enough reputation to vote it up as useful, sorry!

Comment: So I guess I have to delete my answer :(

Comment: @MichaelRiess you can't vote up, but you can mark this as accepted answer

Comment: @rafael you really didn't need to delete your answer - I was going to upvote it because without it (and the following comment thread) I would not have even given my suggested improvement. So "thanks" anyway.